# codeigniter Date_Format in DB->select

Tags: codeigniter

Can someone tell me how to correctly use the following query using codeigniter:

```
DATE_FORMAT(sr.dateCreated,'%m/%d/%Y @ %h:%i %p') AS dateCreated
```

ive tried:

```
 public function viewSR($id) {
        $this->db->select('sr.id
                            ,sr.woid
                            ,sr.description
                            ,DATE_FORMAT(sr.dateCreated),'%m/%d/%Y @ %h:%i %p') AS dateCreated
                            ,sr.startTime
                            ,sr.endTime
                            ,rt.name AS rateName'); 
        $this->db->from('service_report sr');
```

any help would be very grateful!

Comment: do you get an error? what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code like this:

```
    public function viewSR($id) {
      $this->db->select("sr.id
                        ,sr.woid
                        ,sr.description
                        ,DATE_FORMAT(sr.dateCreated,\"%m/%d/%Y @ %h:%i %p\") AS dateCreated
                        ,sr.startTime
                        ,sr.endTime
                        ,rt.name AS rateName",FALSE); 
     $this->db->from('service_report AS sr');
```

or try modify your code this way:

```
function list_all($lang, $limit = FALSE, $offset = FALSE)
{

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d.%m.%Y à %H:%i:%s') AS datetime");

    $this->db->where('lang', $lang);
    $this->db->limit($limit);
    $this->db->offset($offset);
    $this->db->order_by('datetime', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get('news');

    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'd prefer the 1st way you mentioned, but i get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%' in /home/logicpsa/public_html/login/application/models/workorders_model.php on line 153

Comment: still a no go, the other method you offered works, but id still prefer to use the 1st method.

Comment: did you put the false at the end? if you did put than what is the error message

Comment: Sorry there was problem with DATE_FORMAT bracket ) so i edited now it works fine for me check it out.